# DragDelta Event is not woking for Stylus and Touch very first time

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I'm using `Adorners` for re-sizing the Object in my Application. It is working fine for Mouse, but for stylus and Touch it is not working very first time.

I used the code for selecting the object from the following sample provided by MSDN:  [ResizingAdorner Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771714%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

After investigating a lot, I came to know one thing. i.e. `SizeChanged` event is not firing very first time.